# How to set child parameters in apex http callout?

Tags: apex, httppost, stripe

I am trying to create a stripe checkout session using an apex http callout.

I am having difficulty setting line_Items as parameters. In java I would build them as such-

```
List<Object> lineItems = new ArrayList<>();
Map<String, Object> lineItem1 = new HashMap<>();
lineItem1.put(
  "price",
  "price_1LtudSLtxbTPZo1djMsJqSd2"
);
lineItem1.put("quantity", 1);
lineItems.add(line_item1);
Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
params.put("line_items", lineItems);
```

How would I construct this in apex to fit into my current integration as below?

```
HttpRequest req1 = new HttpRequest();
req1.setMethod('POST');
string endpoint='https://api.stripe.com/v1/checkout/sessions';
req1.setEndpoint(endpoint);

String username = 'xxxxx';
Blob headerValue = Blob.valueOf(username);
String authorizationHeader = 'Bearer ' + username;
req1.setHeader('Authorization', authorizationHeader);
String payLoad = 'cancel_url=https://www.google.com&success_url=https://www.google.com&mode=payment&line_items=';
req1.setBody(payLoad);
Http binding1 = new Http();
HttpResponse response1 = binding1.send(req1);
system.debug(response1);
system.debug(response1.getBody());
```

Comment: Hello! :) 
`String payLoad = 'cancel_url=https://www.google.com&success_url=https://www.google.com&mode=payment&line_items=';` Why is it not a JSON?

Comment: Thanks for getting back. The format needs to be url encoded